# MySQL How do you INSERT INTO a table when a SELECT subquery returning multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create an insert statement, below is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO Role (application, developer, role) 

VALUES (? , 
(SELECT Id from Developer WHERE firstName='Alice' and lastname='Wonderland'), 
'ARCHITECT');
```

In the missing value field, I am trying to do a join, the following join statement returns the VALUES I need:

```
   SELECT a.id 
FROM Application a
JOIN application d ON d.id = a.id and a.category='GAMES'
```

However, when I insert the previous query into the missing value field in the insert statement, it gives me an error stating that the query returned more than 1 row (which is intentional, seeing as I want ALL rows returned to be inserted into the role table)

Can anyone provide me feedback on how to fix this issue?

Comment: You can only insert one row at a time, so you'll need to find a way to do this one-by-one.

Comment: That join you have makes no sense. You are joining the same table on the same id column. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @Donal, yes the join statement works fine outside of the value field. If you have a better way to setup the join statement, let me know.

Comment: @McAdam331: you *can* insert more than one row at a time. Either by using `insert into ... values (1,1), (2,2)` or by using `insert into ... select ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, good catch. My mistake. Also, OP, I think Donal's question is, there's no need to join a table with itself. Why not just select from that table? A simpler way to get all `GAMES` applications would be: `SELECT id FROM application WHERE category = 'GAMES';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
INSERT INTO Role(application, developer, role)
    SELECT a.id, (SELECT Id from Developer WHERE firstName = 'Alice' and lastname = 'Wonderland'),
           'ARCHITECT' 
    FROM Application a JOIN
         application d
         ON d.id = a.id and a.category = 'GAMES';
```

Note:  I was going to move the subquery with `Developer` into the `FROM` clause.  However, if there are no matches, this will return `NULL` -- which seems to be your intention.  If I put it in the `FROM` clause, you will get no matches (MySQL doesn't have a `left cross join`).

Answer (score 0):

Incorporate your other parameters into your select statement

```
INSERT INTO Role (application, developer, role)
SELECT ?, Id, 'ARCHITECT' FROM Application a 
JOIN application d ON d.id = a.id and a.category='GAMES'
```

Comment: How would this look? (the SQL statement) I don't get how to create an insert statement that handles every element I need, as well as the join without using a value field.

Comment: Just like this. An INSERT INTO with a SELECT statement after it will insert all the rows returned by the SELECT

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct to get this done. A mock up query would look like below

```
INSERT INTO Role (application, developer, role)    
select a.id,
dev.Id,
'ARCHITECT'
FROM Application a
JOIN developer dev on a.Id = dev.Id
WHERE a.category='GAMES'
AND dev.firstName='Alice' 
and dev.lastname='Wonderland'
```

Comment: In this case how would i set the value of "role"? Its a string. Also, the developer's first name and last name are used to obtain its developer id.

Comment: Follow along the answer. Hope that helps.